# "Should have meant"

Tags: grammar

In one of my recent edits, I revised a sentence from this wording:

> I said surely she meant *seeing as*, not *seems*, (she’s used this word in a similar way before). She replied:

to the following wording:

> When I asked her that she should have meant *seeing as* not *seems* (because she’d used this word in a similar way before), she replied:

However, I was berated and told that the rewording would not pass muster with native speakers. Is there something grammatically or otherwise wrong with the above sentence?

Comment: Please provide a complete sentence.

Comment: Not only is it grammatically wrong, it is very difficult to figure out what you wanted it to mean.

Comment: @petershor- what's grammatically wrong about it?

Comment: What's wrong is you can use "asked her whether", "asked her if", "asked her about", "told her that", but not "asked her that".

Comment: @petershor- google books doesn't agree. http://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&source=mog&hl=en&gl=us&tab=wp&q=%22asked%20her%20that%22&sa=N

Comment: Almost all of those instances are using *that* as a pronoun, while your usage implies that it is introducing a subordinate clause, which is not right, just as Peter Shor said. The first result on the linked page is doggerel.

Comment: @Noah I noticed that a couple of the entries (like [this one](http://tinyurl.com/bululq6)) that _do_ use a similar construction to yours, are (IMHO, poorly) translated works. It is possible that you are convinced of your revision's rightness because it would be grammatically correct in your first language. Just a thought ... :)

Comment: @Noah: Your link to 2M GB entries for *"asked her that"* is misleading, as coleopterist indicates. You should have searched for ["asked her that **she**"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22asked+her+that+she%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22asked+her+that+she%22&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&psj=1&ei=E6gZUND6HuWX1AX92IGwCQ&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=a5a5246462bf5075&biw=1306&bih=905), which has only 19 hits (none of which match your context anyway, so far as I can see).

Comment: One of the entries in your Google search for "asked her that she" is a word-for-word translation of Old English, so if you go back far enough, it's grammatical.

Comment: @PeterShor- Does it mean we should avoid reading *old literature*? I have been reading some novels from the early nineties and I am not sure if it would have a bad effect on my writing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular construction really shows up the weaknesses in Google Ngrams. I just searched for [ask him that he](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ask%20him%20that%20he&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) - if you follow the link, you'll see a graph which suggests it's relatively common. In fact, the actual hits are 1700-1839:**3**, 1840-1901:**1**, 1902-1976:**7**, and [1977-2000](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ask%20him%20that%20he%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1977,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en#q=%22ask%20him%20that%20he%22&hl=en&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1977,cd_max:2000,lr%3alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=qqoZUJCGFvS20QXB84D4Bg&start=20&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=87db1b6ab4e489aa&biw=1306&bih=905):**23**.

I don't take this as evidence that the construction is gaining acceptance - probably it's just become easier for non-native speakers to get work published in English over recent decades.

I'm not sure there's a grammatical rule involved here, but idiomatically you can

> *Ask someone to do something*, or
>
> *Ask **that** someone does something*, but native speakers simply don't say
>
> **Ask someone **that** they do something.* (it sounds "archaic" to me, but I don't know it was ever used)

Answer (score 1):

> When I **asked** her **that she should have** meant seeing as, not seems,( because she'd used this word in a similar way before), she she replied:

You appear to be asking and telling at the same time.

A reworded version using 'ask' could look something like the following:

> When I asked her if she meant "seeing as" rather than "seems" (as she's used this word in a similar way before), she replied ...

... and using 'tell':

> When I told her that she surely meant "seeing as" rather than "seems" (as she's used this word in a similar way before), she replied ...

Also, there really isn't all that much wrong with the original sentence besides its rather colloquial and conversational nature.

Comment: Let's not forget the "she she"

Comment: Fixed that. It was a typo.

Comment: And, of course *should have meant* may be grammatical (though on the borderline), but there are almost no situations where it's meaningful.

Comment: @TimLymington- Are you serious? *"If “sovereignty” means complete autonomy, self-government, self-determination, and freedom from external interference, then “tribal sovereignty” **should have meant that** the Indian tribes were entirely independent of both the United States and ..."*

Comment: @Noah; isn't that 'should mean'?

Comment: @TimLymington- Nope.

Answer (score 0):

The original wording was clear and grammatical. You cannot ask and make a statement at the same time. 'Should have meant' seems both ungrammatical in this context and uncomfortable in use. I am afraid that you were berated for vandalising the previous text, albeit with good intentions!